# Why is my fingerprint sensor not responding to my arduino code?

Tags: arduino, fingerprint

I have bought a GT-511C1R fingerprint scanner, to work in combination with my Arduino Mega. I used this example: http://www.homautomation.org/2014/10/11/playing-with-finger-print-scanner-fps-on-arduino/

But when i try to blink the led using the default code which came with the library

```
#include "FPS_GT511C3.h"
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"

// Hardware setup - FPS connected to:
//    digital pin 4(arduino rx, fps tx)
//    digital pin 5(arduino tx - 560ohm resistor fps tx - 1000ohm resistor - ground)
//      this brings the 5v tx line down to about 3.2v so we dont fry our fps

FPS_GT511C3 fps(4, 5);

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    fps.UseSerialDebug = true; // so you can see the messages in the serial debug screen
    fps.Open();
}


void loop()
{
    // FPS Blink LED Test
    fps.SetLED(true); // turn on the LED inside the fps
    delay(1000);
    fps.SetLED(false);// turn off the LED inside the fps
    delay(1000);
}
```

it doesn't do anything. On my serial monitor i get:

```
FPS - Open
FPS - SEND: "55 AA 01 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 01 01"
```

but the LED of the finger scanner stays off. In combination with my Arduino Uno it does work. What can be the problem?

EDIT: After the answer of changing the pins, it worked just 1 time via pin 10 and 11. After removing the power, it didn't work anymore. Also not on other pins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all pins are supported for `SoftwareSerial` on the Mega; the RX pin must be an interrupt-on-change pin. The list of such pins:

```
10, 11, 12, 13, 50, 51, 52, 53, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69
```

Basically, change the pins in your object to, say, 10 and 11. I would suggest using the hardware serial ports, which the Mega has in abundance, but from my brief perusal, your library seems hardwired to use `SoftwareSerial` and isn't so easily adapted.

Comment: Mmmm. That's weird. The led was blinking, but after uploading another sketch to Enroll fingerprints, it wasn't working anymore. Even after reüploading the blinking led sketch it didn't respond. The pins were still in 10 and 11. Also in the sketch. Any idea?

Comment: @MartijnvanKekem What sketch is running now? Have you tried powering it off and on again? You were careful to include the resistors like before?

Comment: @TristeAndii I'm running the same sketch as given above. I uploaded it after trying to Enroll some fingerprints using the default code of the library. The circuit didn't change. All the resistors stayed on his place. I also tried powering off and on.

Comment: @MartijnvanKekem The resistors are to be connected to pin 11 now! Else you are sending 5 V signals to the 3.3 V device.